# open url in webview when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

So I've got a button which I'm trying to use as a means for the user to navigate to a specific URL (which it does), however the button is opening the url in safari, and i want it to be presented in my web view.

Here is my view controller.swift file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myProgressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Home_button: UIButton!


    var theBool: Bool = false
    @IBOutlet weak var refresh_button: UIButton!
    @IBAction func go_home(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:"my url")! as URL)
    }
    var myTimer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self

        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(webViewDidStartLoad(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        let websiteurl  = URL(string: "another url")
        let websiteurlrequest = URLRequest(url: websiteurl!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                                           timeoutInterval: 10.0)

   webView.loadRequest(websiteurlrequest)


    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        //if let myProgressView.progress is not nil{
        myProgressView?.progress += 0.045
        //}

    }


    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        let loadinglabel = self.view.viewWithTag(100)
        loadinglabel?.removeFromSuperview()
        myProgressView?.progress = 100
        myProgressView?.removeFromSuperview()

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func go() {
        myProgressView?.progress += 0.005
    }
}
```

How do I open the url in the web view on the button press, rather than in safari?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IBAction func go_home(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:"my url")! as URL)
       webView.loadRequest(websiteurlrequest)
    } 
remove webView.loadRequest(websiteurlrequest) from viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Should work in Swift 3

```
@IBAction func go_home(_ sender: UIButton) {
yourWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!))
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! would never have gotten to that!

Comment: Happy coding brother!

Answer (score 1):

Change your button action method like this:

```
@IBAction func go_home(_ sender: UIButton) {
            webView.loadRequest(websiteurlrequest)
    }
```

and remove `webView.loadRequest(websiteurlrequest)` method from viewDidLoad. Then your webView load content when click on button.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the button action area

```
self.openWebURL(url: webUrl)
```

Function to load URL

```
func openWebURL(url : URL)
  {
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

SFSafariViewControllerDelegate should be added to class header like thise

```
class YourClassName: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
```

Hope this helps...